How to prevent the 'default_native_password is deprecated' error in mysql?
I have the default password functionality enabled in mysql version 8.3.0.
I am intentionally using this functionality.
MySQL is writing to the error log:
''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use caching_sha2_password instead

just under 100 times a second. Over the course of a few weeks, this has exhausted the hard drive space of my 80GB server.
How can I prevent MySQL from complaining about the use of this setting ?
An aside
I am aware of the general_log = off parameter and value pair to disable 'general' logs. This does not disable error logs.
If I cannot find a means to cease this error, I will likely alter the error log location to be /dev/null.
However, it would be nice to be able to remove this message in either case.
Specs
MySQL version 8.3.0.
Linux version 20.04.6 (focal fossa).

https://play.datalude.com/blog/2024/02/mysql-8-mysql_native_password-deprecation-error-my-013360/ set global log_error_suppression_list='MY-013360' ; has been reported elsewhere as a solution, did you try this?

As per the link by @Charlieface in the OP comments,hopefully, the following will work for you:
MySQL has deprecated the mysql_native_password authentication plugin, which has been superseded by caching_sha2_password. This deprecation leads to frequent warning messages you are seeing.
You can either suppress these warnings or address the root cause by updating user accounts to use the recommended authentication plugin.
You can suppress the warmings by adding the error code MY-013360 to the log_error_suppression_list. This can be done dynamically without restarting the server:
SET GLOBAL log_error_suppression_list = 'MY-013360';

To make this change persistent across server restarts, add the following line to your MySQL configuration file in the [mysqld] section:
log_error_suppression_list = 'MY-013360'

After editing the configuration file, restart the MySQL server to apply the changes.
